# <script> tags aren't working in Wordpress

Tags: javascript, facebook, wordpress, facebook-graph-api

All,
I have some script tags that are not working in Wordpress. If I have the following code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
      appId      : '<?= 1234?>',
      status     : true, 
      cookie     : true,
      xfbml      : true,
      oauth      : true,
    });

    FB.Event.subscribe('auth.login', function(response) {
      window.location.reload();
    });
  };

  (function(d){
     var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk'; if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
     js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
     js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
     d.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(js);
   }(document));
</script>
```

When I preview this in my browser it looks like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
      appId      : '123',
      status     : true, 
      cookie     : true,
      xfbml      : true,
      oauth      : true,
    });</p>
<p>        FB.Event.subscribe('auth.login', function(response) {
      window.location.reload();
    });
  };</p>
<p>      (function(d){
     var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk'; if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
     js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
     js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
     d.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(js);
   }(document));
</script>
```

Which I believe is causing the program not to execute what is in the script tags. How can I prevent this from happening?

Comment: How are you inserting the script tags? Are you editing the theme files?

Comment: @Blender No, I created my login page as a Page in Wordpress and then I inserted my script directly into there. I did add this <?php remove_filter ('the_content', 'wpautop'); ?> to my template page but if I do that then it doesn't even recognize the <script> tags at all.

Comment: Usually, I just create a custom Page template and insert all that code into there. Then when I create the Login page, I just choose it to be a "Custom Login Page" (or whatever you named it).

Comment: @Blender I was just doing that as you responded. That worked great! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to put that script in the template not in the content editor.

Answer (score 0):

Wordpress converts script tags in the editor to their HTML entity even in HTML mode.  Therefore you can't add JavaScript this way.